# Priority Fee for Legacy Transaction

Tags: fees

Good day friends,

I'm curious if there is a way to see what the priority fee is on a legacy transaction. I always remember using metamask and being able to select options to increase the speed, but when I look on etherscan at legacy transactions there is no mention of priority fees.

For example, on [this transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbadb2e5b522b83b56e6d11447f43a39aae5790c1d2964a78e3d732af16e3b8b8?fbclid=IwAR2g4wP9fCkpGEarNEeCBkD_ynmjIO5JqfcQ7IN6I63GVF_Q2Nnc0Qpgg1Q), I multiply the base gwei by the used gas and then subtracted that from the total transaction cost to try and see if there was something left over which may be a priority fee, but there isn't. Does that mean the priority fee was 0 Gwei? Or is it hidden somewhere else?

Any insights would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Priority fee is a feature of `EIP-1559`. Those transactions that are `EIP-1559` are called `Type-2` transactions.

However, `EIP-1559` is backward compatible, meaning that old (legacy) transactions are still in use and don't have a priority fee which is why you do not see any.